# How to extract dependency jar to specific folder during compilation?

Tags: sbt

These are my project's dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  "com.company" % "common_2.11" % "2.3.3"
)
```

In `com.company.common_2.11-2.3.3` there is a jar file `common_2.11-2.3.3-adtnl.jar`.

How can I during compilation process in `build.sbt` tell SBT to extract its contents to specific folder in my project?

Answer (score 2):

Use the following in `build.sbt`:

```
def unpackjar(jar: File, to: File): File = {
  println(s"Processing $jar and saving to $to")
  IO.unzip(jar, to)
  jar
}

resourceGenerators in Compile += Def.task {
    val jar = (update in Compile).value
            .select(configurationFilter("compile"))
            .filter(_.name.contains("common"))
            .head
  val to = (target in Compile).value / "unjar"
  unpackjar(jar, to)
  Seq.empty[File]
}.taskValue
```

It assumes that `"common"` is a unique part amongst all of your dependencies. You'd need to fix `filter` otherwise.

It also assumes that you don't really want the files at `compile`, but a bit later when `package` is called. You'd need to move the code between `Def.task{...}` to `compile in Compile` block like:

```
compile in Compile <<= (compile in Compile).dependsOn(Def.task {
  val jar = (update in Compile).value
            .select(configurationFilter("compile"))
            .filter(_.name.contains("common"))
            .head
  val to = (target in Compile).value / "unjar"
  unpackjar(jar, to)
  Seq.empty[File]
})
```