# How to declare zip dependency and know its path in file system?

Tags: sbt

I would like to download a zip artifact and find the corresponding file in local repository.

Where I can declare the zip extension ?

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.acme" % "audit-agent" % "0.7" % "test" // ??? where I put zip ?
)
```

May be, I can just use some object to reference the artifact, download it, and file the filename ?

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `from` method of [sbt.ModuleID](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/api/index.html#sbt.ModuleID) in `libraryDependencies` as described in [Explicit URL](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Library-Management.html#Explicit+URL):

```
libraryDependencies += "organization" % "myModuleName" % "1.0" from "https://myhost.pl/slinky.zip"
```

Then follow [How to extract dependency jar to specific folder during compilation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26274698/1305344) and use `update` and `.filter`:

```
val jar = (update in Compile).value
            .select(configurationFilter("compile"))
            .filter(_.name.contains("myModuleName"))
            .head
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a more native way:

```
libraryDependencies += "org" % "name" % "rev" artifacts(Artifact("name", "type", "ext"))
```

or in your case

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"com.acme" % "audit-agent" % "0.7" % "test" artifacts(Artifact("audit-agent", "zip", "zip")))
```